# Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction - While statement

Tags: mysql, sql

When I called my procedure I got this error message:

```
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

my query:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_Convert_Members_to_Users_With_Credits;
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_Convert_Members_to_Users_With_Credits`()
BEGIN

    DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

    START TRANSACTION ;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tb_tmp_sp_convert_members_to_users_with_credits;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tb_tmp_sp_convert_members_to_users_with_credits
    (INDEX tm_converts_index (username), UNIQUE tm_unique_converts_index (username))

    SELECT m.username                                      AS username,
           maddress.mob                                    AS mobile,
           m.name                                          AS name,
           m.family                                        AS family,
           m.email                                         AS email,
           m.n_code                                        AS national_id,
           m.sex                                           AS sex,
           maddress.tel                                    AS tel,
           FROM_UNIXTIME(m.birthday)                       AS birthday,
           FROM_UNIXTIME(m.wedding_date)                   AS wedding_date,
           FROM_UNIXTIME(m.spouse_birthday)                AS wife_birthday,
           maddress.address                                AS address,
           'fa'                                            AS lang,
           'real'                                          AS type,
           102                                             AS country_id,
           IF(maddress.province_id, (SELECT id FROM province_old_province WHERE p_id = maddress.province_id),
              NULL)                                        AS province_id,
           IF(maddress.province_id, (SELECT id FROM city_old_city WHERE c_id = maddress.city_id),
              NULL)                                        AS city_id,
           IF(morders.total_price, morders.total_price, 0) AS total_price_user,
           c.credit                                        AS credit,
           FROM_UNIXTIME(m.reg_at)                         AS created_at
    FROM members m
             LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM address WHERE address != '' GROUP BY user_id) maddress
                       ON maddress.user_id = m.username
             LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(totalPrice) AS total_price, user_id
                        FROM orders
                        WHERE pay_status = 1
                          AND order_status = 4
                        GROUP BY user_id) morders
                       ON morders.user_id = m.username
             LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                        FROM credit
                                 INNER JOIN (SELECT max(cr_id) AS maxId FROM credit GROUP BY username ORDER BY cr_id) A
                                            ON A.maxId = credit.cr_id) c ON c.username = m.username
    WHERE m.level = 'customer'
    ORDER BY m.user_id DESC LIMIT 1;


    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_tmp_sp_convert_members_to_users_with_credits INTO n;
    SET i = 0;
    WHILE i < n
        DO

            SET @username = '';
            SET @credit = 0;
            SET @total_price_user = 0;
            SET @level_id = 1;

            SELECT username, credit, total_price_user
            INTO @username,@credit,@total_price_user
            FROM tb_tmp_sp_convert_members_to_users_with_credits
            LIMIT i,1;
            SET @USER_ID = 0;
            IF (EXISTS(SELECT user_id FROM Tb_Users WHERE username = @username))
            THEN
                SELECT user_id INTO @USER_ID FROM Tb_Users WHERE username = @username;
                IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM Tb_Factors WHERE customer_id = @USER_ID))
                THEN

                    IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Tb_Credits WHERE user_id = @USER_ID))
                    THEN

                        UPDATE Tb_Credits
                        SET type_id     = 14,
                            value       = @credit / 10000,
                            `last_value`=@credit / 10000,
                            creator_id  = 8402
                        WHERE user_id = @USER_ID;

                    ELSE
                        INSERT INTO Tb_Credits (user_id, type_id, value, `last_value`, creator_id, created_at)
                        VALUES (@USER_ID, 14, @credit / 10000, @credit / 10000, 8402, CURRENT_TIME());

                    END IF;


                END IF;

            ELSE

                SET @total_price_user_level = @total_price_user / 10000;

                IF (@total_price_user_level <= 170)
                THEN
                    SET @level_id = 1;
                ELSEIF (@total_price_user_level > 170 AND @total_price_user_level <= 1600)
                THEN
                    SET @level_id = 2;
                ELSEIF (@total_price_user_level > 1600 AND @total_price_user_level <= 1700)
                THEN
                    SET @level_id = 3;
                ELSEIF (@total_price_user_level > 1700 AND @total_price_user_level <= 50000)
                THEN
                    SET @level_id = 4;
                ELSE
                    SET @level_id = 5;
                END IF;


                INSERT INTO Tb_Users(username, mobile, name, family, email, national_id, sex, tel, birthday,
                                     wedding_date, wife_birthday, address, lang, type, country_id,
                                     province_id, city_id, created_at, password, level_id, creator_id)
                SELECT username, mobile, name, family, email, national_id, sex, tel, birthday,
                        wedding_date, wife_birthday, address, lang, type, country_id, province_id, city_id,
                        created_at, NULL, @level_id, 8402
                FROM tb_tmp_sp_convert_members_to_users_with_credits
                LIMIT i,1;

                SET @LAST_ID_INSERTED_USER_ID = 0;
                SET @LAST_ID_INSERTED_USER_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

                INSERT INTO Tb_Credits (user_id, type_id, value, `last_value`, creator_id, created_at)
                VALUES (@LAST_ID_INSERTED_USER_ID, 14, (@credit / 10000), (@credit / 10000), 8402, CURRENT_TIME());


                INSERT INTO Tb_Role_User (user_id, role_id, roleable_id, roleable_type, active)
                VALUES (@LAST_ID_INSERTED_USER_ID, 17, NULL, NULL, 1);

            END IF;


            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;


    COMMIT;

    SELECT 1;

END
```

my temporary table has just one row (limited) and it made successfully.
but I don't know my `while` not finished (I think).

I used `SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 1200` but I got the same error after 1200 seconds.

Comment: Lock waits occur if your session is trying to lock rows that are already locked by another concurrent session. So another session is running concurrently and holding locks for an extended time (1200 seconds or more). You need to make sure other sessions finish promptly and release their locks.

Comment: You should look into using a [CURSOR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html) instead of running repetitive SELECT...LIMIT statements in a loop.